# Foundation alert show only when success

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

Hello so I have 2 php files

index.php

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
<div data-alert class="alert-box success radius">
Message sent.
<a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
</div>
<input type="text" name="txt_message">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<script>
 <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
 $(document).foundation();
 $('.alert-box > a.close').click(function() { $(this).closest('[data-alert]').fadeOut(); });
 </script>
```

send.php

```
if(!empty($_POST['txt_message'])) {
 echo "<script>alert('Message will be sent shortly...').location.href='index.php';</script>";
} else {
 echo "<script>alert('Message not sent').location.href='index.php';</script>";
}
```

What I want to do is to show only the success data-alert when message is sent.. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must hide the data-alert on page loading `$('.alert-box').hide()`,

add an ID to your form `<form id="form" action="send.php" method="POST">`

and match the submit event `$('#form').submit({$('.alert-box').show();});`

On this event you can check the field validity before to show the alert box